# Redirecting to an other page based on url

Tags: php, redirect

I am looking to have a page like this [http://mydomain.com/A.php?url:http://mydomain.com/B.php](http://mydomain.com/A.php?url%3ahttp://mydomain.com/B.php)

I want the visitor to load page A and automatically after a second be directed to what ever link the URL variable is (in my example its B.php)

I tried a few things my self, couldn't get it.

Any help?

thank you!

Comment: What did you try, and how did it not work?

Comment: Make `A.php?url=linktowhatever.com` and check `$_GET['url']` in your `A.php` script. **NOTE** This is not the way to do it as it presents vulnerabilities and warrants abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `A.php`

put something like :

```
header("Location: B.php");
exit();
```

if you want some parameters to be passed from `A.php` do something like:

```
 $url =   $_GET["url"];
header('Location:'.$url);
    exit();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer but I get a 404 not found page because it doesnt seem to actually get the $URL it just forwards to me $URL